# How to read level changes from log4j.xml when application is running

Tags: log4j

I am running a executable jar file, which logs using log4j.xml(version 1.2).

Whenever i change the log level in the xml file, i have to restart the java application for the new log level to reflect.

Can i add some configuration in the log4j.xml so that new log level will be taken into account without application restart?

Thanks,
-Venkat

Comment: If you are using log4j 2.x version, it has the ability to automatically detect configuration changes. There is a parameter called "monitorInterval" that you can set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40429122/1849366

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 1.x has reached end of life on August 5, 2015. So I would like to recommend you to use log4j 2.x which supports this with the monitorInterval [configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

However according to the log4j 1.x docs [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a2.2) it does support log level changes runtime.

> How can I change log behavior at runtime?
>
> Log behavior can be set using configuration files which are parsed at
>   runtime. Using configuration files the programmer can define loggers
>   and set their levels.
>
> The PropertyConfigurator defines a particular format of a
>   configuration file. See also the examples/Sort.java example and
>   associated configuration files.
>
> Configuration files can be specified in XML. See log4j.dtd and
>   org.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator for more details.
>
> See the various Layout and Appender components for specific
>   configuration options.
>
> In addition to configuration files, the user may disable all messages
>   belonging to a set of levels. See next item.